# How to conditional format RANGE of cells based on multiple multiple columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, cell-formatting

[image]

conditional format  right side multiple columns(green highlight) based on what is data put on left side multiple columns

hi all i want to format  right side i.e. green filled cells if the data matched what is on left side columns. every time i have to choose  "equal to"  conditional format  for  cell individually  I have tried to select range but it is invalid for range(i.e. all the columns on left side ).... also note that the column on left side will increase as per data requirement in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MATCH()` function if CF custom formula rule. Try-

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(G1,$B:$B,0))
```

[image]